# How to prevent Text from spreading VStack?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

This is what I have in code:

```
VStack(spacing: 2) {
    Text("23:11:45") or "23:11"
        .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: mode.underlayBackgroundColor))
        .font(.liberationMonoRegular(withSize: 46))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .scaledToFill()
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    ProgressView(value: progress, total: 1)
        .tint(Color(uiColor: mode.underlayBackgroundColor))
        .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: mode.underlayBackgroundColor)
        .opacity(0.3))
}
.fixedSize()
.background(.blue)
```

VStack is wrapped into:

```
ScrollView {
}
.background(.red)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

here is version for "23:11:45"

[image]

here is version for "23:11"

[image]

As you can see the Text with `23:11:45` String extends VStack although it should change the scale of the font. What to do to make it working? Maximum width is 100% - padding for both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `fixedSize` propagates down and tells the `Text` **not** to scale down.

Compare:

[image: text laid out with and without the fixedSize modifier within a frame(width: 50). With the fixedSize modifier, the Text spills out wider than the 50-point width. Without the fixedSize modifier, the Text shrinks to try to fit within the 50-point width.]

Here's the code that generated that image:

```
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("with fixedSize:")

        VStack {
            Text("Hello world")
            Text("Hello world")
                .font(Font.custom("Palatino", fixedSize: 46))
        }
        .fixedSize()
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .frame(width: 50)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))

        Spacer().frame(height: 40)

        Text("without fixedSize:")

        VStack {
            Text("Hello world")
            Text("Hello world")
                .font(Font.custom("Palatino", fixedSize: 46))
        }
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .frame(width: 50)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
```

It doesn't matter if the `fixedSize` comes before or after the `minimumScaleFactor`. It does matter if it's before or after the `frame`.

Comment: But I think it doesnt meet my requirements. Because I cannot put there fixed wdith. It depends on the width of the string in Text View. It changes ONLY when width of the string is out of bounds of parent View. Here VStack.